# Quicksort with Hoare's Partition Algorithm

Tags: quicksort

I've came across Hoare's partition algorithm in Cormen. After analysis I think that the algorithm isn't working as I expected. Let's suppose that we've array [4,3,2,1], then  in my opinion partition is returning 0, so next quicksort calls will be QS(A,1,0), QS(A,1,4), the second one is the same as first call so this array won't be sorted ever (infinite recursion).

```
Partition(A,p,r)
x = A[p]
i = p-1
j = r+1
while True do
   repeat j-=1
      until x>=A[j]
   repeat i+=1
      until x<=A[i]
   if i<j then
      swap(A[i], A[j])
   else
      return j

QS(A,p,r)
q = Partition(A,p,r)
QS(A,p,q)
QS(A,q+1,r)
```

Comment: Please double check your reasoning, especially the indices. Have you implemented the pseudocode in your favorite programming language? What is the result if you run it? Have you done the exercise "Hoare partition correctness" in the book? `QS(A,1,0)`?

Comment: Once upon a time I have analyzed variations of this algo: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/92562/question-regarding-hoares-partitioning-scheme-and-a-slight-modification-to-it/93702#93702

Comment: I also had some trouble implementing this. I was integrating this into a dynamic language where you can easily test the @#$% out of something. In one line I can generate all permiutations of a sequence, sort them, and `uniq` them to test that they are all identical to each other, and compare to the tested result. I simply iterated on tweaking the details until that test case passed: all possible permutations of 1..9 were being sorted to 1..9. Then added larger test cases.